# Run javascript function each time

Tags: setinterval

I need to run any js function each 1 second(for example), i want to make my functions as parameters. to run them any time.

My code is:

```
var refresh = function(callback, period) {
    return window.setInterval(function() {
        callback;
    }, period); 
};

var mFunction = function() {
    console.log(new Date());
};
```

and to run that

```
refresh(mFunction, 1000);
```

but i can't get it.

any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated:

```js
var mFunction = function() {
    console.log(new Date());
};

var refresh = window.setInterval; // <- Just an alias, not really needed.

refresh(mFunction, 1000);
```

The same could be written as:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log(new Date());
}, 1000);
```